# Rethinkdb multiple fields with different ordering

Tags: rethinkdb

Is it possible to do order_by on multiple fields with different ordering?

```
r.table("users").order_by(r.desc("age") & r.asc("name"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Just take a look at the RethinkDB `orderBy` [documentation](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/order_by/):

```
table.orderBy([key | function...], {index: index_name}) → table_slice
selection.orderBy(key | function[, ...]) → selection<array>
sequence.orderBy(key | function[, ...]) → array
```

Note the ellipsis (`...`) that marks a variadic method allowing arbitrary number of arguments. Therefore your query becomes as following:

```
r.table("users")
  .order_by(r.desc("age"), r.asc("name"))
```

Despite the document I've referenced above describes the JavaScript driver implementation, it will go also for other standard drivers (you're probably using Python or Ruby).

Comment: Thank you very much. This saved me a lot of money. Sorry for the late response, but i just noticed the answer.